# Syslog beeing spammed by Audit when a Docker container (vaultwarden) is running

Tags: linux, docker, logging, audit, syslog

My VM is a Debian 11 that i use with Docker to have a Vaultwarden server for my enterprise. The issue is : the disk get filled way too fast because of the syslog file that receives about 20 lines each minute. Those lines don't show up when my container is off so i think that it's linked ofc.

`Jun 23 15:15:06 vaultwarden-test audisp-syslog: type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1687526106.339:1211809): proctitle=72756E6300696E6974`

`Jun 23 15:15:06 vaultwarden-test audisp-syslog: type=EOE msg=audit(1687526106.339:1211809):`

`Jun 23 15:15:06 vaultwarden-test audisp-syslog: type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1687526106.339:1211810): arch=c000003e syscall=157 success=yes exit=0 a0=2f a1=3 a2=28 a3=0 items=0 ppid=16884 pid=16895 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="runc:[2:INIT]" exe="/" subj=unconfined key=(null) ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=prctl AUID="unset" UID="root" GID="root" EUID="root" SUID="root" FSUID="root" EGID="root" SGID="root" FSGID="root"`

It's always this group of 3 lines.

Also, i've got an audit daemon running in the background, it apparently gets everything that appends on the machine to print it into syslog, user.log etc...

I tried to set docker's log level to 'error', even 'fatal' but it doesn't change anything, also changing rsyslog.conf but it doesn't work either. I tried too many fixes but nothing works, help pls

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.